# How to click on a marker on the google map for Xamarin UITest

Tags: google-maps, user-interface, testing, xamarin

I write Xamarin UITest for Android app. In the app uses google map. Help me please, how to click on a marker on the map?

Comment: Are you asking how to programmatically simulate a marker click, respond to a marker click event, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building the app yourself, I suggest checking out backdoor methods. These are methods that you can build into the app and then call from the test.

There are plenty of examples for Obj-C and Java apps. Here's an example for C# backdoor methods, which you'd put in either your MainActivity or AppDelegate classes: http://danatxamarin.com/2015/05/07/configuring-backdoor-methods-in-c-for-xamarin-test-cloud/

I'd create a backdoor to return whatever data you need about the map, and then use `app.Invoke("myNewMethod");` which will return a string (which could be json). This string could contain screen coordinates, which you could then pass to `app.TapCoordinates(x, y);`.

The short answer is, Google Maps on Android doesn't really expose objects in an automatable way, so the second best option is backdoors.

Answer (score 1):

markers are not showing within the tree of views, my guess is that they're drawn on screen within the map framelayout.

given that the marker is at the center of the map, you could tap it using something like this :

*(with a map fragment of id "map")*

```
var map = app.Query("map")
var middleX = (map.First().Rect.Width + map.First().Rect.X) / 2
var middleY = (map.First().Rect.Height + map.First().Rect.Y) / 2
app.TapCoordinates(middleX, middleY)
```

but I think that's all you can do within the map itself.

Comment: I can simply click on the map and get to the center. But a few marker on the map and I have to click on one of them. How can I find the coordinates of the markers?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because markers don't appear as subviews of the map, UITest can't query them

Comment: it seems feasible with iOS maps, not Android. 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/38034/need-advice-on-ui-testing-maps

Comment: Thank you. I think so too. But I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom renderer for android you can simulate a click inside, the main trick is to access markers inside the renderer:

```
var field = this.GetType().BaseType.GetField("_markers", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var markers = (List<Marker>)field.GetValue(this);
```

now for any element in `markers` as you cannot send a real click you can just simulate it. Pasting the code from my live project:

```
  protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == "ExternalClickedPin")
        {
            if (FormsControl.ExternalClickedPin != null)
            {
                var pin = Map.Pins.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MarkerId == FormsControl.ExternalClickedPin.MarkerId);
                if (pin != null)
                {
                    var field = this.GetType().BaseType.GetField("_markers", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                    var hiddenMarkers = (List<Marker>)field.GetValue(this);

                    var marker = hiddenMarkers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == pin.MarkerId.ToString());
                    if (marker != null)
                    {
                        //simulating click
                        //1 invoke clicked event
                        // pin.SendMarkerClick(); // <- if needed for tests
                        //2 show info on map
                        marker.ShowInfoWindow(); //just what i was needing
                        //3 center pin on map
                        //Map.MoveToRegion(...); <- not here, im calling this from Forms subclassed control
                    }

                }
                FormsControl.ExternalClickedPin = null;
            }



        }
    }
```