# call the click event on the Pin Map control Xamarin forms pcl

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I'm looking online but could not find anything, I'm using the Map control Xamarin forms pcl.
And I must say that I find the event to trigger when I click on the Pin on the map (google maps).
Can anyone advise me? thank you.

```
var map = new Map(
                    MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                        new Position(lat, lon), Distance.FromMiles(50)))
                    {
                        IsShowingUser = true,
                        HeightRequest = CrossScreen.Current.Size.Height,
                        WidthRequest = CrossScreen.Current.Size.Width,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                    };

                    RGL_Locations = RGL_Locations.OrderByDescending(x => x.RGL_DateTime).ToList();

                    foreach (RGL_Locations item in RGL_Locations)
                    {
                        map.Pins.Add(new Pin { Type = PinType.Generic, Label = item.RGL_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS.ToString(), Position = new Position(item.RGL_Latitudine, item.RGL_Longitudine) });
                    }

                    map.Pins.Add(new Pin { Type = PinType.Generic, Label = "Io sono qui!", Position = new Position(lat, lon)});

                    var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
                    stack.Children.Add(map);
                    Content = stack;
```

SOLUTION:

```
foreach (RGL_Locations item in RGL_Locations)
                    {
                        var pin = new Pin
                        {   
                            Type = PinType.Place,
                            Position = new Position(item.RGL_Latitudine, item.RGL_Longitudine),
                            Label = "Clicca qui per aprire",
                            Address = "Numero di serie macchina: " + item.RGL_MCC_Numero_Serie_MS.ToString()
                        };

                        pin.Clicked += Pin_Clicked;

                        map.Pins.Add(pin);                        
                    }
```

Comment: might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/61084281/7149454

Answer (score 4):

The `Xamarin.Forms.Map` `Pin` class has a `Clicked` event:

```
var position = new Position(32, -13); 
var pin = new Pin
{
    Type = PinType.Place,
    Position = position,
    Label = "custom pin",
    Address = "custom detail info"
};
pin.Clicked +=  (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    var p = sender as Pin;
};
```

ref: [Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Pin.Clicked](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Pin.Clicked/)

Comment: you can also bind to a list of pins? your example refers to a single object, how can I do to connect the event to all pins of the list?

Comment: @Mr.Developer You would need to assign the same Event delegate to each of your Pins... You could always write an List Extension to that does the assignment via refection....